# MATLAB: Per-element min operation on cell object

Tags: matlab

I have a cell object of size nx1 which contains a matrix of size mxnxk at each coordinate.

As an output, I would like to get a matrix of size mxnxk which is the result of per-pixel min operation for all the matrices in the cell.

I currently use a for loop, but I prefer using something more elegant.

code example:

```
%example for an input (in my case m,n and k are much bigger)
m = 4; n=3; k=2;
relevanceCell = {rand(m,n,k),rand(m,n,k),rand(m,n,k)}

%prints input
relevanceCell{:}

%for loop for calculating the per-pixel minimal value.
minRes = relevanceCell{1};
for ii=2:length(relevanceCell)
    minRes = min(minRes,relevanceCell{ii});
end

%prints output
minRes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate them through the 4th dimension and then apply `min` function on that dimension:

```
minRes = min(cat(4,relevanceCell{:}),[],4);
```

To be more generic, you can find the number of dimensions of the arrays and adapt to that:

```
nextDim = 1 + ndims(relevanceCell{1});
minRes = min(cat(nextDim,relevanceCell{:}),[],nextDim);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is a good idea, which works good for a case were k=1. It won't work if k>1. I modified my question so that the example which I gave won't be confusing.

Comment: Then your matrices are 3-dimensional and you need to act on 4th dimension. I update the answer.